# Is there a way to get Java 9 to stop complaining about inaccessible packages?

Tags: java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am switching to Java 9 (for the HTTP/2 client, among other benefits), but do not plan on using Java 9 modularization.

I'm getting tons of compiler errors about inaccessible packages. Each one requires me to add an additional `--add-exports modulename/packagename=ALL-UNNAMED` compiler flag.

Is there some compiler flag that I can specify, one time, to add all exports and not get any more compiler errors?

Here is example code showing the problem:

```
package com.prosc.fx;

import com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper;

public class CompilerFlagTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WindowHelper.getWindowAccessor();
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> Error:(3, 22) java: package com.sun.javafx.stage is not visible (package com.sun.javafx.stage is declared in module javafx.graphics, which does not export it to the unnamed module)

Comment: Can you expand the question to include an example? At a guess you are trying to compile code with references to JDK internal classes.

Comment: Edited question to show example. Many of the classes are in the sun.* and com.sun.* packages.

Comment: Don't use that class: it's in a private package. Use public API, not private API. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx.graphics-summary.html

Comment: Just a side note, *switching to Java 9 (for the HTTP/2 client, among other benefits), but do not plan on using Java 9 modularization.* ... that's making use of less than half or rather quarter goodness of migrating to Java9.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the benefits of modilarization for us are very minor since shrinking the JVM is a non issue on server and I don’t care about the encapsulation changes. The downsides are significant, especially the restriction that the same package cannot exist in multiple modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classes and packages you mention are in private packages, a new visibility level in the ladder. Meaning that you may not access them, because the whole modularisation is mandatory, not optional. Even when you don't use modularisation, you're using it.

So do yourself a favour and use the public API.

Comment: The option you are talking about that is going to be removed is `--illegal-access`, **not** `--add-exports`. As far as I know the latter is here to stay.

Comment: @Nicolai My bad, I removed that bit. Thanks!